# Using adjustbox type functionality with supertabular

Tags: tables, multicolumn, adjustbox, supertabular

I am trying to add a long table to a two column latex document. Since the table is long, without continuing in the 2nd column, it continue in the first column like below.

[image]

Following is the current code that I am using.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Exceptions encountered by participants and their reactions}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.4\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Context}&\textbf{Exception message} &\textbf{Reaction of the participant} \\
    ...
    ...
    \end{tabular}
    \label{exceptions}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

I am also using `adjustbox` as I need to break the text inside the table cell.

Now I need to break my table to continue in the next column. I read and tried to use `supertabular`as follows.

```
    \begin{supertabular}{lll}
    \hline
    \textbf{Context}&\textbf{Exception message} &\textbf{Reaction of the participant} \\
    ...
    ...
    \end{tabular}
```

But now my table looks as below.[image]

My 3rd column is no longer in the page. How can I solve this?

Comment: Neither table nor adjustbox will allow page breaks. `l` columns will always print their content in one line.

Comment: why have you changed the `p` columns (which allow line breaks) to `l` columns (which do not)? that is the change causing the problem nit the change from tabular to supertabular.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments for the question, I tried following code and it worked.

```
    \begin{supertabular}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.4\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Context}&\textbf{Exception message} &\textbf{Reaction of the participant} \\
    ...
    ...
    \end{tabular}
```